# ggplot stacked area plots depicting high y-axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, ggplotly

I am using `ggplot` to set up my plots and then using `ggplotly` to render as a `plotly` plot so that I can do tooltips and such. The problem I'm running into is that it seems like every plot I make using this method has the y-axis scale all out of whack. [Edit: this seems to only happen with stacked area plots and the issue starts in ggplot2... see end of post.] Example plot below and then code for how I'm creating the plot:

[image]

As you can see, the total value of the traces I'm hovering over come to a little over 120K, but the y-axis says that it should be over 800k. What's causing this, and how do I fix it?

```
Boundary_plot <- ggplot(Boundary, aes(timestamp,time)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = component,color=component)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#440154','#46327e','#365c8d','#277f8e','#4ac16d','#a0da39','#fde725')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#440154','#46327e','#365c8d','#277f8e','#4ac16d','#a0da39','#fde725'))

ggplotly(Boundary_plot, dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>%
  rangeslider() %>%
  layout(hovermode = "x")
```

Also, here's what the data looks like (taken from RStudio):

[image]

ETA: I've tried setting limits in `scale_y_continuous`, which works in ggplot2 but in ggplotly causes some weird graphical problems:

[image: ggplot2 rendering with scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(value))) set]

[image: ggplotly rendering with scale_y_continuous([etc]) set]

Comment: Are you sure you only have 1 row for each component at each timestamp? Seems likely you have multiple rows of data getting added together in the area chart, but the hover is only showing one of them.

Comment: If you need more help please find a small sample of data that reproduces the problem. We can't run your code and debug it using a screenshot of a table as input--something like `Boundary %>% filter(timestamp %in%  c("2022-06-24 09:17:20", "{other adjacent timestamp}")) %>% dput()` to give a copy/pasteable version of a couple of timestamps near the problem.

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you so much. I piped the dataframe that I pulled in from the CSV supplying my data into distinct() and that fixed everything. I didn't even notice the duplicate rows, because it's a large dataset and I just assumed there was something differentiating them somewhere.